# Missing Approve / Reject message moderation buttons

Tags: exchange, email-server, microsoft-office-365, outlook-2013

When a message is send a message to a typical moderated distribution list, the moderator gets the familiar Approve / Reject buttons and this works for the test group I setup as part of a "your decision is requested" e-mail. This message comes from "Microsoft Exchange on behalf of ". This e-mail cannot be forwarded until a decision is made.

However when I enabled moderation on all other groups, the moderator gets the "your decision is requested" e-mail but it doesn't contain the approve / reject group even though they are also both the moderator and the owner of the group. This message comes from "Microsoft Exchange Approval Assistant  on behalf of ". This e-mail can be forwarded.

According to the message headers the failing group is `X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-FromEntityHeader: HybridOnPrem` and the working group is `X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-FromEntityHeader: Hosted`

That said using the exchange management console I can run `get-distributiongroup` on both groups with no visible relevant differences. Both groups show in ECP and office 365 portal.

Is it just the case that I mail enabled the security group today and the whole environment hasn't caught up, or how do I diagnose the issue further?

Answer (score 1):

After the weekend the issue resolved itself, one possibly theory is that after the global address list updated the security groups are now routed as local.